# Difference between String.valueOf(int i) and printing only i

Tags: java, string, casting, value-of

See the below code snippet:

```
int count = 0;
String query = "getQuery"; 
String query1 = "getQuery";
final String PARAMETER = "param";

query += "&" + PARAMETER  + "=" + String.valueOf(count);
query1 += "&" + PARAMETER  + "=" + count;
System.out.println("Cast to String=>"+query);
System.out.println("Without casting=>"+query1);
```

Got the both output exactly same. **So I am wondering why this has been used when we can get the same result by using only `count`.**

I got some link but did not found exactly same confusion.

Comment: Why are you expecting a different output?

Comment: Understand that when you concatenate a String literal and an int (or any primitive type), the int (or primitive) is automatically converted to a String.

Comment: I am not expecting any different output but want to know the reason why this has been used. (If any of cource)

Comment: It's used when you **don't** concatenate a primitive with a String literal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is well explained in the [JLS - 15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator +](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> If only one operand expression is of type `String`, then string conversion ([§5.1.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11)) is performed on the other operand to produce a string *at run time*.

You should note the following:

> The `+` operator is syntactically *left-associative*, no matter whether it
>   is determined by type analysis to represent string concatenation or
>   numeric addition. In some cases care is required to get the desired
>   result.

If you write `1 + 2 + " fiddlers"` the result will be

```
3 fiddlers
```

However, writing `"fiddlers " + 1 + 2` yields:

```
fiddlers 12
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for -- a reference to the JLS. Thanks. 1+

Answer (score 1):

Java compiler plays a little trick when it sees operator `+` applied to a `String` and a non-string: it `null`-checks the object, calls `toString()` on it, and then performs string concatenation.

That is what's happening when you write this:

```
query1 += "&" + PARAMETER  + "=" + count;
//        ^^^   ^^^^^^^^^    ^^^
```

You can certainly do this when the default conversion to `String` is what you want.

However, if you do this

```
String s = count; // <<== Error
```

the compiler is not going to compile this, because there is no concatenation. In this situation you would want to use `valueOf`:

```
String s = String.valueOf(count); // <<== Compiles fine
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.valueOf(int)` actually calls `Integer.toString()`.

So, it is used to convert an `int` to a String **elegantly**. As, doing `i+""` is IMNSHO, not quite elegant.

Moreover, when you print any number directly, it actually calls the `toString()` method of its Wrapper class, and the prints the string.